# Multiple options for the same argument in ArgumentParser Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

I was wondering if it is possible to give multiple options for the same arguments in ArgumentParser.

I am aware that it is possible to do it by giving "-" in addition to "--" for the same argument. For example:

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--dataset_name', type=str)
```

The previous code is legit. However, I was wondering if the following code is still valid?

```
parser.add_argument('--dn', '--dataset_name', type=str)
```

Now I have specified two arg options with "--" for the same argument.

Another question I have is that if the following code is correct?

```
parser.add_argument('-dn', '--dataset_name', type=str)
```

Here I am giving two character for the option defined with "-".

Comment: Have you tried?  You'll get an error `argparse.ArgumentError: argument -dn/--dataset_name: conflicting option string: --dataset_name`

Comment: Try using a list of multiple options `['-d', '-n']`

Comment: I know, I was wondering if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar, I would like to give two letter or more for the name of the option like --dn besides --dataset_name. I do not know how to do it,

Comment: Options that begin with a single hyphen are always single-letter options.

Comment: @Barmar, How about having two options with "--" for the same argument? I mean consider parser.add_argument('--dn', '--dataset_name', type=str). It seems to  me that this gives error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,
Try this,

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="FooBar")
parser.add_argument("--foo", "--bar") #<-- by default the output will be on 1st option `foo`

parser.parse_args("--foo 5".split()) #--> Namespace(foo='5')
parser.parse_args("--bar 5".split()) #--> Namespace(foo='5')
```

You can also set the `dest` i.e. the variable in namespace the value will end up in.

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="FooBar")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--foo", "--bar", dest="baz")

parser.parse_args("-f 5".split())    #--> Namespace(baz='5')
parser.parse_args("--bar 5".split()) #--> Namespace(baz='5')
```

But you cannot use two characters for options with single `-`
single `-` represents single char options that can even be clubbed together, eg. `command -a -b -c` can be written as `command -abc` provided `a` and `b` don't expect values.